# Express.js - abort request on timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am exploring ways to abort client requests that are taking too long, thereby consuming server resources.
Having read some sources (see below), I tried a solution like the following (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944570/1229582)):

```
const express = require('express');
const server = express();
server
    .use((req, res, next) => {
        req.setTimeout(5000, () => {
            console.log('req timeout!');
            res.status(400).send('Request timeout');
        });
        res.setTimeout(5000, () => {
            console.log('res timeout!');
            res.status(400).send('Request timeout');
        });
        next();
    })
    .use(...) // more stuff here, of course
    .listen(3000);
```

However, it seems not to work: the callbacks are never called, and the request is not interrupted.
Yet, according to [recent posts](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4664#issuecomment-893767852), it should.

Apart from setting the timeout globally (i.e. `server.setTimeout(...)`), which would not suit my use case,
I have seen many suggesting the [connect-timeout](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/timeout.html) middleware.
However, I read in its docs that

```
While the library will emit a ‘timeout’ event when requests exceed the given timeout, node will continue processing the slow request until it terminates.
Slow requests will continue to use CPU and memory, even if you are returning a HTTP response in the timeout callback.
For better control over CPU/memory, you may need to find the events that are taking a long time (3rd party HTTP requests, disk I/O, database calls)
and find a way to cancel them, and/or close the attached sockets.
```

It is not clear to me how to "find the events that are taking long time" and "a way to cancel them",
so I was wondering if someone could share their suggestions.
Is this even the right way to go, or is there a more modern, "standard" approach?

Specs:

- Node 12.22
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Linux 5.4.0-87-generic

Sources:

- [Express.js Response Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708208/express-js-response-timeout)
- [Express.js connect timeout vs. server timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364401/express-js-connect-timeout-vs-server-timeout)
- [Express issue 3330 on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330)
- [Express issue 4664 on GitHub](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4664)

**Edit**:
I have seen some answers and comments offering a way to setup a timeout on **responses** or "request handlers": in other words, the time taken by the middleware is measured, and aborted if it takes too long. However, I was seeking for a way to timeout **requests**, for example in the case of a client sending a large file over a slow connection. This happens probably even before the first handler in the express router, and that is why I suspect that there must be some kind of setting at the server level.

Comment: Well depends on what is taking a long time exactly. If you are blocking the main thread there's not much to do o think. But if its some async call wrapped in a promise, you could wrap it in bluebir's timeout promise : http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/timeout.html

Comment: If you don't have control over that time expensive task, I think that the only proper way is `process.exit` which will terminate whole instance and all child processes(async). It will lead you to [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster) which takes care of respawning new worker when any of them die for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Before rejecting long request, I think, it's better to measure requests, find long ones, and optimize them. if it is possible.

## How to measure requests?

Simplest way it is to measure time from start, till end of request. You'll get `Request Time Taken` = `time in nodejs event loop` + `time in your nodejs code` + `wait for setTimeout time` + `wait for remote http/db/etc services`

If you don't have many setTimeout's in code, then `Request Time Taken` is a good metric.
(But in high load situations, it becomes unreliable, it is greatly affected by `time in event loop` )

So you can try this measure and log solution
http://www.sheshbabu.com/posts/measuring-response-times-of-express-route-handlers/

## How to abort long request

it all depends on your request handler

### Handler does Heavy computing

In case of heavy computing, which block main thread, there's noting you can do without rewriting handler.

if you set req.setTimeout(5000, ...) - it fires after res.send(), when main loop will be unlocked

```
 function (req, res) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    //blocking main thread loop
  }
  res.send("halted " + timeTakenMs(req));
}
```

So you can make your code async, by injecting setTimeout(, 0) some where;
or move computing to [worker thread](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

### Handler has many remote requests

I simulate remote requests with Promisfied setTimeout

```
async function (req, res) {
    let delayMs = 500;
    await delay(delayMs); // maybe axios http call
    await delay(delayMs); // maybe slow db query
    await delay(delayMs);
    await delay(delayMs);
    res.send("long delayed" + timeTakenMs(req));
  }
```

In this case you can inject some helpers to abort your request chain
`blockLongRequest` - throws error if request time is too big;

```
async function (req, res) {
    let delayMs = 500;
    await delay(delayMs); // mayby axios call
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs); // maybe db slow query
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs);
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs);
    res.send("long delayed" + timeTakenMs(req));
  })
```

### single remote request

```
function (req, res) {
    let delayMs = 1000;
    await delay(delayMs);
    //blockLongRequest(req); 
    res.send("delayed " + timeTakenMks(req));
}
```

we don't use blockLongRequest because it's better to deliver answer instead of error.
Error may trigger client to retry, and you get your slow requests doubled.

## Full example

(sorry for TypeScript, `yarn ts-node sever.ts` )

```
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      start?: bigint;
    }
  }
}

const server = express();
server.use((req, res, next) => {
  req["start"] = process.hrtime.bigint();
  next();
});
server.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error("Error captured:", err.stack);
  res.status(500).send(err.message);
});

server.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("pong " + timeTakenMks(req));
});
server.get("/halt", function (req, res) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    //halting loop
  }
  res.send("halted " + timeTakenMks(req));
});
server.get(
  "/delay",
  expressAsyncHandler(async function (req, res) {
    let delayMs = 1000;
    await delay(delayMs);
    blockLongRequest(req); //actually no need for it
    res.send("delayed " + timeTakenMks(req));
  })
);
server.get(
  "/long_delay",
  expressAsyncHandler(async function (req, res) {
    let delayMs = 500;
    await delay(delayMs); // mayby axios call
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs); // maybe db slow query
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs);
    blockLongRequest(req);
    await delay(delayMs);
    res.send("long delayed" + timeTakenMks(req));
  })
);

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Ready on 3000");
});


function delay(delayTs: number): Promise<void> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, delayTs);
  });
}
function timeTakenMks(req: Request) {
  if (!req.start) {
    return 0;
  }
  const now = process.hrtime.bigint();
  const taken = now - req.start;

  return taken / BigInt(1000);
}
function blockLongRequest(req: Request) {
  const timeTaken = timeTakenMks(req);
  if (timeTaken > 1000000) {
    throw Error("slow request - aborting after " + timeTaken + " mks");
  }
}

function expressAsyncHandler(
  fn: express.RequestHandler
): express.RequestHandler {
  return function asyncUtilWrap(...args) {
    const fnReturn = fn(...args);
    const next = args[args.length - 1] as any;
    return Promise.resolve(fnReturn).catch(next);
  };
}
```

I hope, this approach helps you to find an acceptable solution

Comment: Sorry, but I think there is a misunderstanding here: you are suggesting an approach to abort **responses** (or, "request handlers") if they take too long. The question was seeking for a way of aborting **requests**: I will edit the question for clarity.

Comment: Considering your example in edit: "sending a file on a slow connection" - slow connection is not a problem: node.js is async, and it will process large file chunk by chunk(not taking match CPU time). Maybe there's a problem with simultaneously handing many big files and memory consumption for storing them(you can limit body size, save body stream to hard drive). Maybe you have a problem handling many connections(what is your limit?). So if you describe the full particular task with problems you have encountered, someone could give you a more precise answer.

Comment: @Mike slow connections *are* actually a problem in the cosmic sense. It's a type of denial of service attack.